# How does the new training time in supercell works with dark barak or unupgraded barracks that cannot produce a unit?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Should I upgrade my barracks to the same level?

Say I have 3 barracks upgraded to healer. Say 1 barrack is upgraded to dragon.

Say, for simplicity sake, a healer, a golem, and a dragon cost 1 hour to make. I know that's far from true. It's for simplicity sake.

Normally if I want 3 healer and 1 dragon, I would need 1 hour.

Under new system, how long will it take for to get 1 dragon and 3 healers?

I supposes the dragon will take 1 hour because only 1 barrack can create that one dragon and somehow that one barrack will held up all other barracks while creating that one dragon.

Then, the 3 healers will take 45 minutes each.

So, under current system, it's slower, if you have different level barracks.

Say in addition you have a dark barrack. Say a golem cost 1 hour.

Under old system, you can get 3 healers, 1 dragon, and 1 golem in 1 hour.

Now you will need 2.45 hours (1 for dragon, 1 for golem, and 45 minutes for the healers).

Am I even correct?

So basically, if only one barrack can produce a unit, will that unit takes very long to build while preventing all other barracks from producing anything?

Comment: What *is* the new training system?

Comment: Are you talking about the one from October of 2016?

Comment: The one where we train the whole troop rather than selecting barrack to train those troops.

Comment: You mean quick train?

Comment: Is it what it's called? How do I know? URL? The current training time where we don't have to specify which barrack train what.